# Cómo separar con un espacio dos <xsl:value-of select="marca"/> <xsl:value-of select="modelo"/> en XSL

Tags: html, css, xml, xsl

estoy realizando una práctica de XML+XSL, donde se solicita crear una ficha de usuario con `<xsl:for-each select*...`, la primera fila de la ficha debe aparecer con dos elementos, en este caso:

```
<p><xsl:value-of select="nombre"/>
<xsl:value-of select="apellidos"/></p>
```

Pero si lo ejecuto en la web de esta forma, salen pegados, por ejemplo:
`AntonioSalas`, he probado colocando un nbsp; entre medias pero da error.

Gracias de antemano y un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si utilizas XSLT versión 1.0 o realmente cualquier versión puedes utilizar la función `concat` e introducir un `' '`, por ejemplo

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(nombre, ' ', apellidos)"/>
```

En caso de versión 2 o 3 también puedes usar

```
<xsl:value-of select="nombre, apellidos" separator=" "/>
```

Otro método sería utilizar `xsl:text`, por ejemplo

```
<xsl:value-of select="nombre"/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="apellidos"/>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Martin, me ha funcionado con los dos métodos.